# Enable Root Access Lumia RM-1090 With Windows Phone Internals

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, jailbreak

I want to enable root access on my windows phone Lumia RM-1090 with Windows Phone Internals. But there is some command that make me confused :

1. On the Menu "Platform-Flash", there is a message : When you flash an original FFU, the phone will be restored to its original configuration. All unlocks, apps and data will be removed from the phone!.
2. On the Menu "Unlock-Unlock bootloader", there is a message : You should also select a folder where you have Lumia Emergency Flash Loaders. This tool will try to select the Loader that is suitable for your phone.

My question is :

1. where i can find the original FFU file ?
2. where is the location of Lumia Emergency Flash Loaders ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use "Windows Device Recovery Tool". It will download FFU and place it at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Packages\Products`
2. These are not available to general public. As I understand, they're stolen somewhere because they have valid OEM signature and allow you to disable secure boot. You will probably find some at XDA-Developers.